How to install nvm in windows
I have already installed node but I need to downgrade versions and I was thinking on using nvm.
I am trying to install nvm in windows with the following command on my cmd with admin rights:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
But I got the following:
C:\windows\system32>curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0The system cannot find the path specified.
 49 16555   49  8226    0     0  88636      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 92426
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

How can I correctly install the nvm?

Actually you are trying to perform command of ubuntu/mac on windows.
If you want to install NVM in windows then please refer this step by step guide.
Step by step guide
NVM For Windows
